# Question about outer regularity and inf

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a measure. Suppose for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists an open set $U \supset E$ such that $\mu(U) < \mu(E) + \varepsilon$. Then must $\mu(E) = \inf\{\mu(U): U \supset E, U \text{ open}\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Since the opens sets contain $E$ all their measures are greater than or equal to the measure of $E$ so the inf of their measures is greater than or equal to measure of $E$.

On the other hand, the first statement easily implies that the inf must be less than or equal to the measure of $E$.